# obtener datos consulta sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

esta es mi base de datos.
https://prnt.sc/ifpk7f

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta que muestre imagenes y nombre de artistas y también quiero obtener una lista de todas las canciones o singles,todo en la misma consulta .

```
SELECT a.* FROM discografica.cancion a
INNER JOIN discografica.singles b ON b.idsingles = a.idsingles
INNER JOIN discografica.grupo c ON c.idgrupo = b.idgrupo 
INNER JOIN discografica.grupo_artista d ON d.idgrupo = c.idgrupo
INNER JOIN discografica.artistas e ON e.idartistas = d.idartistas
INNER JOIN discografica.gestion f ON f.idartistas = e.idartistas
INNER JOIN discografica.personal g ON g.idpersonal = f.idpersonal
```

tengo esto hecho pero que no se si esta bien,y no consigo implementar para que muestre el nombre y imagen del artista.
Gracias

Comment: Conforme valla analizando tu BD te dare observaciones .. por que dos Tablas ? una de Canciones y Single? podrías tenerla en una sola alfin y al cabo son canciones solo con una bandera que te indique si es o no single (Todos lo que te comente son observaciones eres libre de elegirlas o no .. .)

Comment: Como dice @Anyel, tu diseño es **mejorable**. No obstante, para lo que requieres ahora, te falta poner en el `SELECT` las columnas de cada tabla que quieres ver, por ejemplo: `SELECT b.columna-de-la-tabla-singles, c.columna-de-la-tabla-grupo ... y así cada columna de cada tabla que quieres`

Comment: Ya que tienes todo relacionado, solo tienes que llamar en el SELECT los campos que necesitas con su respectivo alias, si tu consulta funciona correctamente, agregale al SELECT a.*, **b.nombre as single** FROM